# How to search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project including .class files and libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project (including .class files and libraries) in Android Studio ?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F , and choose under the search bar scope -> All Places

Comment: try Edit > Find > Find in path

Comment: `.class`es are not humanly readable so It does not makes sense to trace some strings withing that file even it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

For search all the occurrences of a string in android Studio follow the steps.

1. Go to Project explorer window.
2. Select Your App or root folder
3. Right Click on your app
4. Select **Find in Path** option

After that your search window open where you can search for string.

[image: look in image below]

Thank You I hope Its work for you.

Comment: @Yogesh Byndoor try it

Answer (score 0):

right click in the root folder of your project -> find in Path

Comment: Yes, I did that but it will not search in .class files.

Comment: so do the same thing to the folder which contains .class file

Answer (score 0):

You can search any string from entire project using :
`Ctrl+Shift+F` keys

Comment: Yes, I did that but it will not search in .class files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ctrl+shift+f to search for any String in android Studio